# Is there any continuation to Kotzk\ Pershischa today?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism

Is there any sort of continuation to the dynasties of Kotz and Pershischa dynasties which actually adheres to the lifestyle of those chassidim? (I don't mean Ger and the like, which have absolutely nothing to do with that style?)

I think the basic points are not living within a "system" trying to conform to a certain mehalech in avodas Hashem, rather every person finding his own and even in the minute details of day to day life and living and doing mitzvos with the heart of the law not the letter. (This is not a very good explanation but I feel that anyone that has researched the Pershischa rebellion against the rebbes of that time period will understand what I mean.)

Comment: http://kotzkblog.blogspot.com/

Comment: i havent found that website having anything specific to do with kotzk\pershischa

Comment: You might find it easier to garner a response if you explain what the lifestyle of Kotzk/Pershischa was, and what was unique about them. Just saying that Ger isn't that doesn't lend much to finding similarities.

Comment: chortkov2 good point i think the basic points are not living within a "system" trying to conform to a certain mehalech in avodas Hashem rather every person finding his own and even in the minute details of day to day life and living and doing mitzvos with the heart of the law not the letter. this isnot a very good explanation but i feel that anyone that has researched the pershischa rebbelion against the rebbes of that time period will understand what i mean

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Joel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Ideally any response to a comment asking for clarifications on the questions would result into an edit of the original question, not a comment answering it. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @mbloch thanks for your suggestion the question i posed definitely can use some clarification i am a bit stuck as how to proceed as the kotz/pershischa lifestyle is a vast and complicated sugya i therefore am trying to figure out how to write as brief a synopsis as possible. for anyone interested in more about this topic there is a grest book written by michael rosen called the quest for authenticity

Comment: Kotzk and pesischa were themselves different styles, despite the one being a continuation of the other

Comment: @Orangesandlemons they most definitely were diff in the details of their mehalchim but in  the overall mehalech i feel they were pretty much the same

Comment: Gur comes from both

Comment: @kouty i specificaly wrote that i dont mean ger as i am looking for a continuation of the idealogy not punkt